# ftp4j download file which size is 0 byte

Tags: java, ftp4j

I download  a file using ftp4j  library, its size is 0 byte. I get no exception. So I use jstack pid ,here is the snippet about ftp.

```
`"Thread-17" #63 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000021154000 nid=0x2bf0 runnable 
[0x00000000275ae000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
    - locked <0x000000076e90ca80> (a java.io.InputStreamReader)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read0(StreamDecoder.java:127)
    - locked <0x000000076e90ca80> (a java.io.InputStreamReader)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:112)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:168)
    at it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.NVTASCIIReader.readLine(NVTASCIIReader.java:105)
    at it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPCommunicationChannel.read(FTPCommunicationChannel.java:142)
    at it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPCommunicationChannel.readFTPReply(FTPCommunicationChannel.java:187)
    at it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPClient.download(FTPClient.java:3390)
    - locked <0x000000076e074080> (a java.lang.Object)
    at it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPClient.download(FTPClient.java:3193)
    at it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPClient.download(FTPClient.java:3098)
    at com.ron.newgen.ftp.FtpDownloadClienter.download(FtpDownloadClienter.java:60)
    at com.ron.newgen.ftp.FtpThread.run(FtpThread.java:56)
    - locked <0x000000076e881c28> (a com.ron.newgen.ftp.FtpThread)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)`
```

It seems that `sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read` is locked  for some reason. But I can not figure out it. `Wireshark` show the last communication.

[image]

DATA SENDING IS OVER! FOR IF I CLOSE THE APPLICATION, THE FILE WILL BE THE SAME  AS THAT ON THE SERVER THAN 0 BYTE.

I searched here, but seems cannot find the one fit my issue.  PLS tell the reason and solution.

Here is my code.

```
  public class FtpJob implements org.quartz.Job 

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
          FtpDownload ftpdownload = new FtpDownload(ftp, -1);
          ftpdownload.download();
  }


  public class FtpDownload(){

        ......

        private FtpDownloadClienter ftp;


        public void download() {

              try {
                    ftp.openConnection();

                    String home = "/home/";
                    String d1 = "";
                    d1 = prefix;
                    String remoteFileName = d1 + ".tar.gz";
                    for(String p:province){
                          log.debug(p);
                          if(!p.equals("jiangsu")){
                                continue;
                          }
                          String remoteFolderPath = home + p +"/" +  d1 + "/";
                          log.info(remoteFolderPath);
                          String clientpath = "f:\\ftp\\";
                          log.info(clientpath);
                          File file = new File(clientpath);
                          if(!file.isDirectory()){
                                file.mkdirs();
                          }

                          ftp.download(remoteFolderPath, remoteFileName, clientpath);
                     }

               } catch (Exception e) {
                     log.debug(e.getMessage(), e);
               }finally{
                     ftp.closeConnection();
               }
      }
  }


  public class FtpDownloadClienter{
        private FTPClient client = new FTPClient();

        public  void openConnection()throws Exception{
              client.connect(ftpHost, ftpPort);
              client.login(ftpUser, ftpPasswd);

        }

           public  void download(String remoteFolderPath, String remoteFileName, String localFolderPath) {



                 try {
                       client.changeDirectory(remoteFolderPath);
                       client.setPassive(true);
                       client.download(remoteFileName, new File(localFolderPath + remoteFileName), new MyTransferListener());
                 } catch (FTPException e) {
                             e.printStackTrace();
                             if(e.getCode() == 550){
                                   System.out.println("File not found : " + remoteFileName  );
                             }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                } finally{
                      log.info("Downloaded" );
                }
            }


  }
```

It works when I don't encapsulate with org.quartz.Job. But I need schedule this `ftp job`.

I change some codes  ,but not work, the funny way of working  remains.

Comment: Probably you don't need to start another thread. I think quartz run its jobs in a threadpool so starting a thread within a thread seems unnecessary. I haven't seen you FtpThread but I bet that you have opened your socket outside of your thread's run, so it is binded to a different thread and that's why this funny way of working.

Comment: @m4gic I change codes, but not work. Would you please give more advice? thanks

Comment: Another possible reason can be your firewall, maybe on the host where you are trying to run your quartz job something blocks the access. Either your outbound firewall rules, or the settings of the ftp server. Please try to download your file with a standard ftp client on the host where your quartz job will run.

Comment: @m4gic Thanks  your reply. I've solved this problem. Every your advise is helpful.